# js TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I upload a photo and give back my uploaded files. Then I map my uploaded files and want to show it with URL.createObjectURL(el) but I got this error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
    at http://localhost:3000/build/routes/cars-YYTVMLAP.js:12722:287
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ModalAddCar (http://localhost:3000/build/routes/cars-YYTVMLAP.js:12722:159)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-GIAAE3CH.js:12171:26)
    at updateFunctionComponent (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-GIAAE3CH.js:14577:28)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-GIAAE3CH.js:15912:22)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-GIAAE3CH.js:19749:22)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-GIAAE3CH.js:19194:20)
    at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-GIAAE3CH.js:19133:13)
    at renderRootSync (http://localhost:3000/build/_shared/chunk-GIAAE3CH.js:19112:15)
```

So how can I preview images with react ?

```
const [previewImages, setPreviewImages] = useState<string[]>([]);

// in array is this file
// {_name: 'WhatsApp_Image_2023-09-21_at_18.49.59-removebg-preview.png', _lastModified: 1696505275556}

{
  previewImages.length > 0 && previewImages.map((el) => (console.log(el),
    <ImagePreview imgUrl={URL.createObjectURL(el)} key={el} onPressRemove={handleRemoveImage} />
  ))
}
```

So why I got the error message above ? I have a file in my array.

Comment: What are you trying to do? you can just pass the file source (path) to the image component to show the image. I don't think you need `createObjectURL` for that, unless you are trying to show a `Blob`, `File` or `Buffer` objects

Comment: its a File Object but cant show it because I got this error. When I dont use URL.createObjectURL(el) then in img component it is like this src="[Object Object]"